# Azure SSL site no longer working after reboot - connections reset

Tags: ssl, azure

I'm working on a site that exposes endpoints over HTTP and HTTPS through Azure Web roles.

We've done some updates to the database, and to force the sites to re-populate their cache we've rebooted the roles. Now, however, the SSL endpoints no longer work - connections to the server are broken.

We've tried reimaging the instances, which also didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question to serve as reference for the future:

We'd removed the certificate used for Remote Desktop access to the site.

Interestingly, this caused the SSL side of the site to fail, but only on a reboot.

Our fix was to replace the certificate, then do a full redeploy to staging and a VIP swap.

It does appear that the load balancer is *very* sensitive to its certificate configuration. I've found before that if there's any issues with *any* of the certificates in a package that the load balancer just stops working with no error in the log.